# The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) asp error (Not hosted on IIS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am trying to learn how to set data to the Telerik chart I added to my webpage. I figured it would be as simple as the common control that comes with Visual Studio, I was wrong. I have read through many different articles on how to fix this problem but I still get the same error (what the question is). I am not hosting my page in IIS I have checked that also. Methods I have tried thus far:

1. `<add path="ChartImage.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2011.3.1305.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" validate="false" />`
2. `<system.webServer>
   <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   <handlers>
     <add name="ChartImage.axd_*" path="ChartImage.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" preCondition="integratedMode" />
     <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd_*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" preCondition="integratedMode" />
     <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx_*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" preCondition="integratedMode" />
     <add name="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx_*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode" />
     <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd_*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI"  preCondition="integratedMode" />
   </handlers>
   </system.webServer>`
3. `Server.MapPath to file location(never found where it wasn't for spellcheck)`

These seemed the most promising in my search but it still just tells me in the URL this: /graphtest/ChartImage.axd which is where my chart it is trying to access is located. Now what can I do to fix this that actually works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using a virtual path with name "graphtest" ? the configuration you added is making the /chartImage.axd available at root.

It should work if you run the application without the virtual path.

Comment: No I never declared a virtual path I searched my entire solution for it and never found it.

Comment: check your project url by going to the properties of the project and web (links on the left side) . Remove the "graphtest" if you see that in the url